# How to convert a JSON string to a Map<String, String> with Jackson JSON

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

propertyMap = JacksonUtils.fromJSON(properties, Map.class);
```

But the IDE says:

> Unchecked assignment `Map to Map<String,String>`

What's the right way to do this?
I'm only using Jackson because that's what is already available in the project, is there a native Java way of converting to/from JSON?

In PHP I would simply `json_decode($str)` and I'd get back an array. I need basically the same thing here.

Comment: Where is the class JacksonUtils coming from? I don't see it in any of the Jackson releases.

Comment: It's our wrapper for Jackson, handles some of the JsonFactory and ObjectMapper stuff that you have to do.

Comment: So, the problem is that JacksonUtils.fromJSON() isn't declared to return Map<String, String>, but just Map.

Comment: Btw, don't assign new HashMap there on first line: that gets ignored. Just assing the call.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with your described problem, which has to do with untyped collection. The answer below is the correct answer to what you really tried to ask.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

*[Update Sept 2020] Although my original answer here, from many years ago, seems to be helpful and is still getting upvotes, I now use the GSON library from Google, which I find to be more intuitive.*

I've got the following code:

```
public void testJackson() throws IOException {  
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    File from = new File("albumnList.txt"); 
    TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef 
            = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};

    HashMap<String,Object> o = mapper.readValue(from, typeRef); 
    System.out.println("Got " + o); 
}
```

It's reading from a file, but `mapper.readValue()` will also accept an `InputStream` and you can obtain an `InputStream` from a string by using the following:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(astring.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

There's a bit more explanation about the mapper on [my blog](https://djna.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/json-strings-no-rest-using-the-jackson-parser/).

Comment: @Suraj, it's as per the documentation, and I agree I would not have been able to deduce the formulation from first principles. It's not so much weird as showing that Java is more complex than we might think.

Comment: Krige: I thought the hard bit was getting the mapper going, but I've added the note on how to apply the technique to a string

Comment: One minor comment: the first line of creating `JsonFactory` is not needed. `ObjectMapper` can create it automatically on its own.

Comment: @djna the poster asked for `Map<String, String>` and you've provided `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: To write the Map as a string you can do `mapper.writeValueAsString(hashmap)`

Answer (score 70):

Try `TypeFactory`.  Here's the code for Jackson JSON (2.8.4).

```
Map<String, String> result;
ObjectMapper mapper;
TypeFactory factory;
MapType type;

factory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
type    = factory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, String.class);
mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
result  = mapper.readValue(data, type);
```

Here's the code for an older version of Jackson JSON.

```
Map<String, String> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
    data, TypeFactory.mapType(HashMap.class, String.class, String.class));
```

Comment: TypeFactory.mapType(...) is now deprecated, try this: 

new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>() {}

Comment: @cyber-monk That gets rid of the warnings, but doesn't actually check the types.

Answer (score 40):

Warning you get is done by compiler, not by library (or utility method).

Simplest way using Jackson directly would be:

```
HashMap<String,Object> props;

// src is a File, InputStream, String or such
props = new ObjectMapper().readValue(src, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {});
// or:
props = (HashMap<String,Object>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(src, HashMap.class);
// or even just:
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // suppresses typed/untype mismatch warnings, which is harmless
props = new ObjectMapper().readValue(src, HashMap.class);
```

Utility method you call probably just does something similar to this.

Comment: OP asked for `Map<String, String>` and you've provided `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: @fIwJlxSzApHEZIl  probably because often a JSON object contains values that are not strings, in which case you could use `Object`

Comment: FWIW, I think  `new TypeReference<>(){}` on it's own may be enough, the compiler can do the rest

Answer (score 26):

```
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Map.class);

Map<String, String> map = reader.readValue("{\"foo\":\"val\"}");
```

Note that `reader` instance is Thread Safe.

Comment: @dpetruha OP asked for `Map<String, String>` and you've provided `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 11):

Converting from String to JSON Map:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

map = mapper.readValue(string, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: The above still results in `Type safety: The expression of type HashMap needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,String>`. While this can be suppressed with `@SuppressWarnings` annotation, I'd recommend using `TypeReference` first or casting next as mentioned by Staxman

Comment: To get rid of the type safety warning, you can use `map = mapper.readValue(string, map.getClass());` - given that you have instantiated the map, as is the case here.

Comment: if the type of var is Map<Integer, String>,  Just get the object class is not right.

Answer (score 9):

just wanted to give a Kotlin answer

```
val propertyMap = objectMapper.readValue<Map<String,String>>(properties, object : TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {})
```

Comment: hmmm,  not sure why this was downvoted.  Not only does this line work for me, it also gives the key to doing it the right way.  By replacing Map<String,String> with a different desired type, the mapper will convert the string into any complex collection, like List<MyObject>, or List<Map<String, MyObject>>

Comment: Because the question is "how to do it in Java"

Comment: It's always useful to have a Kotlin-specific answer to a Java question because Kotlin is usually used on the JVM as a replacement for Java. I'm grateful for the Kotlin answer.

Comment: Kotlin as at 2023


`val fromJson: Map<String, String> = objectMapper.readValue(json)`

Answer (score 6):

```
JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParameterizedType(Map.class, Key.class, Value.class);
Map<Key, Value> map=objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, javaType);
```

i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: in java doc : @since 2.5 -- but will probably deprecated in 2.7 or 2.8 (not needed with 2.7)

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me:

```
Map<String, String> propertyMap = getJsonAsMap(json);
```

where `getJsonAsMap` is defined like so:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getJsonAsMap(String json)
{
    try
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<Map<String,String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String,String>>() {};
        HashMap<String, String> result = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldnt parse json:" + json, e);
    }
}
```

Note that this *will* fail if you have child objects in your json (because they're not a `String`, they're another `HashMap`), but will work if your json is a key value list of properties like so:

```
{
    "client_id": "my super id",
    "exp": 1481918304,
    "iat": "1450382274",
    "url": "http://www.example.com"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using Google's Gson

Why not use Google's Gson as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22033974/5320562)?

Very straight forward and did the job for me:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new Gson().fromJson( yourJsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Agreed, the world has moved on, Gson is much, much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the generic solution to this problem.

```
public static <K extends Object, V extends Object> Map<K, V> getJsonAsMap(String json, K key, V value) {
    try {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      TypeReference<Map<K, V>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<K, V>>() {
      };
      return mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Couldnt parse json:" + json, e);
    }
  }
```

Hope someday somebody would think to create a util method to convert to any Key/value type of Map hence this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for Kotlin.

```
class HeathCheckController {
    fun get(): Any {
        val config = this::class.java.getResource("/git-info.yml")?.readText()
        return ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(config, Map::class.java)
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
val jackson = "2.13.2"
```

Comment: !! seems more appropriate than ? for this one.