# Jackson TypeFactory Static Methods Deprecated What to Use?

Tags: java, jackson

Typefactory class at jackson has many deprecated methods inside it. I am using it like that:

```
public List<T> getX(Class<T> clz) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String jsonData = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        a = mapper.readValue(jsonData, TypeFactory.collectionType(List.class, clz));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return a;// a is a global variable
}
```

and it warns me that `collectionType` is **deprecated**. What to use instead of it?

Comment: Use TypeReference instead.

See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json accepted answer.  


  [1]:

Comment: I can not use generics with TypeReference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TypeFactory itself is NOT deprecated, just static methods; instance methods like "constructType" are available. So question is rather where do you get a TypeFactory instance to use.

Most often you get an instance from `ObjectMapper` using its `getTypeFactory` method; or from `SerializationConfig` / `DeserializationConfig`. They carry an instance around.
If none of these works, there is `TypeFactory.instance` as well that you can use.

The reason for deprecation is that some extension modules will want to replace the standard factory: specifically, Scala module needs to extend type handling with Scala Collection (etc) types -- these will not work by default, since Scala does not extend java.util versions.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation and voting up. I will test your sugesstion. Which one do you suggest `getTypeFactory` method from ObjectMapper or `TypeFactory.instance` or it doesn't important which one to use?

Comment: Ideally ObjectMapper.getTypeFactory(), since that may have been overridden. But there is no point in constructing a new Mapper for getting access; so if you don't have mapper (or serialization/deserialization config), just use .instance.

Comment: I have a `mapper` variable and I do: `mapper.readValue(jsonData, mapper.getTypeFactory().collectionType(List.class, clz));` but still it is deprecated?

Comment: collectionType() is static method; use `constructCollectionType` instead.