# Java - Jackson array mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

Given the following JSON

```
{
    "obj" : {
        "f1" : "blah",
        "f2" : "blah",
        "f3" : [{"z1" : "blah", "arr" : [{"m1" : "blah", "m2" : "blah"}]}]
    }
}
```

I have tired using `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonCreator` in order to map `"m1"` and `"m2"` values, but with no luck.

With `@JsonCreator public Card(Map<String,Object> props) { }` i get the following error:

```
Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for MyObj$Obj$Card, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator()}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-paramater constructor annotated as Creator
```

With `@JsonCreator public Card(@JsonProperty("m1") String m1, @JsonProperty("m2") String m2,){}` I get the following error:

```
Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for MyObj$Obj$Card, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator()}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-paramater constructor annotated as Creator
```

How can the fields of `"arr"` be mapped using Jackson annotation?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I also tried to include `@JsonProperty("arr") private Card[] cards;` on `f3` class, but it did not help either.

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed the array type in the update above, and now I do not get the error but it does not behaves as I wish (I would like to handle the mapping).

Is there any chance one could explain the error in a way that I could correct them.

Comment: try @JsonProperty("arr") private List<Card> cards

Comment: @Nailgun, I get the error `No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class MyObj$Obj$Card]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@751bbe4f; line: 1, column: 201] (through reference chain: MyObj["obj"]->Obj["cards"])`. Any clue?

Comment: Could you show the classes you use?

Comment: @eugen, any chance you could elaborate on the error and what causes it?

Comment: Without the classes I am not sure, but if they are inner classes (non static) it is normal that it fails, jackson can not deserialize to this kind of types.

Answer (score 0):

If m1 and m2 are not hardcoded properties than you should use TypeReference to convert json to java map. See this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525152/484894)

Else you can map "arr" with your Arr class having String m1 and String m2 as fields.

Comment: But 'arr' is an array. Hence, it should be mapped to an array or a list of object of which the array holds. Any chance for a snippet regarding your last suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. You can always use Map.entrySet() to access to these objects as a collection. I can imagine how to deserialize {"messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]} or {"messages":["name":"val1","name":"val2"]} to a list but not your example.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the error, i.e. what does the error mean. maybe this will let me fix the issue.