# How to Traverse Complex JSON and put into a Map?

Tags: java, json, tree-traversal

I tried few days to get this done. but could`t .

What i want is Traverse any given JSON and put Key and Value pair into a map. As a sample consider this JSON

```
 String test = {
   "RechargeRequest":{
      "RechargeSerialNo":"2645",
      "RechargeChannelID":"3",
      "RechargeObj":{
         "SubAccessCode":{
            "PrimaryIdentity":"763500001"
         }
      },
      "RechargeInfo":{
         "CashPayment":[
            {
               "Amount":"30"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

What i have tried so far

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(test);
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObj.keys();
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        if (jsonObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {

        }else if(jsonObj.get(key) instanceof  JSONArray){

        }else{

        }
    }
```

Maps value should be like ( "RechargeChannelID","3")
                          (  "Amount":"30")

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks,

Comment: what happens for jsonArray as there could be multiple same key in array so as values ? And in that case, setting values to map will definitely override previous value

Comment: btw, what is problem in your approach? it seems ok though... additionally, you have to do your task recursively inside your `if-else` condition as they may contain nested object. You can write another method and pass the `JSONObject` or `JSONArray Object` whatever you find to get its all nested key-pairs. But you have to consider my first comment for array elements though

Comment: Why did you want to do this? Because the same key may appears in a JSON array or other JOSN node with different levels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten a JSON string to Map<String, String> using Gson or Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759462/flatten-a-json-string-to-mapstring-string-using-gson-or-jackson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to flatten your json file into one level then map it to key and value pairs, kindly check the link below: 
[How to deserialize JSON into flat, Map-like structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355261/how-to-deserialize-json-into-flat-map-like-structure)

Comment: No i want to go through a map and put the each key and value into that map and modify some values in the map