# Java JSON deserialization without predefining everything

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I realize this has probably been asked a hundred times but I have searched a lot and can't find specifically what I'm looking for.

Here is what I'd like. Given a string `data`, I'd like to deserialize into an object `obj` that doesn't have all the fields predefined. I'd like to just be able to ask for the fields I want such as `obj.getString("stringFieldName")` or `obj.getInt("intFieldName")`. I already have gson being used for other things so if it is possible with gson that would be great although not opposed to using another library.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json) might help.

Comment: @user2864740 The de facto standard for JSON processing is Jackson at this point. I have never met anybody using the JEE API directly. So much for a standard :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'standard' Android JSON library (since API 1) already provides such untyped access.

See [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), eg. [getInt](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt(java.lang.String)):

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is an int or can be coerced to an int, or throws otherwise.

Unless needing the JSON mapped onto a 'native' Java collection type this is probably the simplest way to achieve the request. It doesn't require any additional libraries.

Answer (score 1):

With Jackson library you can annotate data model class with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

and the jacksonconverter will just parse only these fields that you defined. Other will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) from Square? It works with GSON and Java Annotations and it's super easy to set up.