# How do I deserialize this JSON using Gson?

Tags: json, gson

I am a bit lost here,

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{  
"type":"fuu",
"message":"bar",
"data":{  
  "5":{  
     "post":"foo",
     "type":"bar",

  },
  "0":{  
     "post":"foo",
     "type":"bar",

  },
  "1":{ 
     "post":"foo",
     "type":"bar",

   },

  // and so on...

 }
}
```

Please how do I parse it into POJOs using Gson? (I need to get the list of objects)

I am a bit confused by the number in front of the elements of the list of objects....

Comment: I don't see any array in your code

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman you are right, edited, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

**Pojo.java**

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Pojo {
    private String type;
    private String message;
    private Map<Integer, InnerPojo> data;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Map<Integer, InnerPojo> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Map<Integer, InnerPojo> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo [type=" + type + ", message=" + message + ", data=" + data
                + "]";
    }
}
```

**InnerPojo.java**

```
public class InnerPojo {
    private String type;
    private String post;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getPost() {
        return post;
    }
    public void setPost(String post) {
        this.post = post;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InnerPojo [type=" + type + ", post=" + post + "]";
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.testgson.beans.Pojo;

public class Main {
    private static Gson gson;

    static {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String j = "{\"type\": \"fuu\", \"message\": \"bar\", \"data\":{ \"0\":{\"post\": \"foo\", \"type\": \"bar\"}, \"1\":{\"post\": \"foo\", \"type\": \"bar\"}, \"5\":{\"post\": \"foo\", \"type\": \"bar\"}}}";
        Pojo p = gson.fromJson(j, Pojo.class);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

**And Result is -**

```
Pojo [type=fuu, message=bar, data={0=InnerPojo [type=bar, post=foo], 1=InnerPojo [type=bar, post=foo], 5=InnerPojo [type=bar, post=foo]}]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!!!! Thanks!! Please did you do it manually or did you use some tool?

Comment: Manually. You can create java class by looking into the JSON string you have.

Answer (score 0):

For the `"data"` part, I'd try to parse it into a `Map<Integer, TypedPost>` structure, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json) for instructions.