# Putting JSON values into Hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have JSON value like below,

```
   { "emp_id": 1017,
   "emp_name": "karthik Y", 
  "emp_designation": "Manager", 
   "department": "JavaJson", 
   "salary": 30000, 
   "direct_reports":
  [ 
  "Nataraj G",
   "Kalyan", 
  "Mahitha" 
  ] 
} 

 HashMap < String, String[] >input1 = new HashMap < String, String[] >();
 input1.put("empid","1017");
 input1.put("emp_name","karthik");
 input1.put("emp_designation","manager");
 input1.put("salary","30000");
```

now I want to add next array that is direct_report to put as next key and value(entire array shoud be come one key and value). Someone please help out.

Comment: what has to be in key and value ?

Comment: Map dbInputMap = new HashMap();
        dbInputMap.put("Parm1", new String[]{emp_id+ ""});
        dbInputMap.put("Parm2", new String[]{emp_name + ""});
        dbInputMap.put("Parm3", new String[]{emp_designation+ ""});
        dbInputMap.put("Parm4", new String[]{department+ ""});
        dbInputMap.put("Parm5", new String[]{salary+ ""}) I also want to put the direct report array to this map and I have pass this map to somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a JSON string to a Map<String, String> with Jackson JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashmap is a key/value storage, where keys are unique. You can convert your JSON to string and then store it as a value to the hashmap. For example something like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{ \"emp_id\": 1017," 
               + "\"emp_name\": \"karthik Y\"," 
               + "\"emp_designation\": \"Manager\"," 
               + "\"department\": \"JavaJson\"," 
               + "\"salary\": 30000," 
               + "\"direct_reports\": [" 
               + "\"Nataraj G\","
               + "\"Kalyan\"," 
               + "\"Mahitha\"]}"; 

        HashMap<String, String> jsonStore = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        jsonStore.put("myJson", json); 

        System.out.println(jsonStore.get("myJson"));
    }
```

You need can also use the '[org.json](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=)' library to

- Create JSON object manually
- Convert existing JSONObject to String representation
- Convert JSON string to JSONObject

You can also have the following solution:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(); 
jsonObject.put("empt_id", 1017); 
jsonObject.put("emp_name", "karthik"); 

HashMap<String, JSONObject> jsonObjectStore = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>(); 
jsonObjectStore.put("myJsonObject", jsonObject); 

HashMap<JSONObject, String> jsonObjectStore2 = new HashMap<JSONObject, String>();
jsonObjectStore2.put(jsonObject, "myJson");
```

Make sure that you download the org.json jar file and put it in your classpath to be able to use the JSONObject. You can download the jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=).

In order to put each of those values into map as single key/value entry. You have mentioned it yourself, it should work without any problem. See below methods:

**Method 1**
Everything in Java is Object, String inherits Object, String[] inherits object. You can have the following solution:

```
HashMap<String, Object> myObjectStore4 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String[] directReports4 = new String[]{"Natraj G", "Kalyan", "Mahitha"}; 

myObjectStore4.put("emp_id", new String("123")); 
myObjectStore4.put("emp_name", new String("Raf")); 
// others .... 
myObjectStore4.put("directReports", directReports4);
```

**Method 2** 
To store the fields as key/value and if you can afford converting the array to String (which represents all array elements comma separated then use this method).

```
HashMap<String, String> myObjectStoreTwo = new HashMap<String, String>();

String[] directReports2 = new String[]{"Natraj G", "Kalyan", "Mahitha"}; 

myObjectStoreTwo.put("emp_id", "123"); 
myObjectStoreTwo.put("emp_name", "Raf"); 
myObjectStoreTwo.put("salary", "222");

//Converts array to comma separated String 
myObjectStoreTwo.put("directReports",Arrays.toString(directReports2));
```

**Method 3** 
In the expense of having Hash Map to store String key and Array value. You have to put other elements as array too.

```
HashMap<String, String[]> myObjectStore3 = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

String[] directReports3 = new String[]{"Natraj G", "Kalyan", "Mahitha"}; 

myObjectStore3.put("emp_id", new String[]{123 + ""});
myObjectStore3.put("salary", new String[]{32312 + ""}); 
myObjectStore3.put("directReports", directReports3);
```

Comment: Direct_report key contains a set of array values. how do I set the set of array value into single key and value.

Comment: To understand it properly your direct report is something like this > String[] directReports = {"Natraj G", "Kalyan", "Mahitha"};  right? if yes, then you could easily add it to a Map<String, String[]> which you mentioned in your question.

Comment: I have modified my question, look once again.

Comment: There are a few methods to do it, I will update the answer to list all the method.

Answer (score 2):

Use a jackson ObjectMapper. Try if this works

```
String json = "{....}"
HashMap<String,Object> mappedVals = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                    json ,
                    new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {
                    });
```