# How to Convert JSON to JAVA Object using ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

- Java Object

  ```
  class B {
     private String attr;
  /***** getters and setters *****/

  } 

  class A {
        private String attr1;
        private String attr2;
        private Map<String,B> attr3;

      /***** getters and setters *****/

  }
  ```
- Json Object

  `json = {attr1 :"val1", attr2 : "val2", attr3 : {attr : "val"}}`

How to convert json to java Object (class java contain Map as type of attribute) ?

Comment: you cant create the object with same name. check your code

Comment: @Hasnain Ali Bohra Thank for your answer, I corrected it

Comment: Please find the below to links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651395/convert-jsonobject-to-string
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914690/putting-json-values-into-hashmap

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jackson to do that:

```
//Create mapper instance
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//Usea a JSON string (exists other methos, i.e. you can get the JSON from a file)
String jsonString= "{'name' : 'test'}";

//JSON from String to Object
MyClass result= mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyClass .class);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It not works when I tried to use Java Class contain a Map like the example above (class A)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library as following:

```
// representation string for your Json object
String json = "{\"attr1\": \"val1\",\"attr2\": \"val2\",\"attr3\": {\"attr\": \"val\"}}"; 

Gson gson = new Gson();
A a = gson.fromJson(json, A.class);
```

Comment: Did you check your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model/POJO which resembles your json structure and then by putting json string in json file you can get java object by using below simple code by using JACKSON dependacy

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File inRulesFile = (new ClassPathResource(rulesFileName + ".json")).getFile();
List<Rule> rules = mapper.readValue(inRulesFile, new TypeReference<List<Rule>>() {
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class PostSaveServiceTest {

    private static final String PATH_TO_JSON = "classpath:json/post-save";

    private static final String EXTENSION_JSON = ".json";

    @Test
    void setData() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Post post = runParseJsonFile(objectMapper);

        System.out.println(post);

    }



    private Post runParseJsonFile(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

        File pathToFileJson = getPathToFileJson(PATH_TO_JSON + EXTENSION_JSON);

        Post post = null;

        try {
            post = objectMapper.readValue(pathToFileJson, Post.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("File didn't found : " + e);
       }

        return post;
    }


        private File getPathToFileJson(String path) {

        File pathToJson = null;

        try {

            pathToJson = ResourceUtils.getFile(path);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return pathToJson;
    }
}
```