# How to hashmap a JSON's key-value pair where Value type and number of key-value pairs not known

Tags: java, json, hashmap, keyvaluepair

I have a JSON in string format coming from DB, about which I only know that it's in key-value format. I don't know beforehand

- How many pairs will be there in JSON string
- type-of Value. It can be String or Object.

Here are some of my JSON String:

- `{"windowHandle":"current"}  \\ in one String: String format`
- `{"type":"implicit","ms":100000} \\ in two String: String format`
- `{"id":"{a67fc38c-10e6-4c5e-87dc-dd45134db570}"} \\ in one String: String format`
- `{"key1": {"sub-key1": "sub-value1", "sub-key2": "sub-value2"}, "key2": {"sub-key2": "sub-value2"}}  \\ in two String: Object format`

So, basically: Number of key-value pair and type of value(String, Object) is not known beforehand.

I want to store this data into my Hashmap. I know that if could be only String: String format, I could do as following `put` in the Hashmap.

**My question is**,

- How I can store json in this case efficiently without iterating over JSON String.
- What should be my Hashmap type, definetily not `HashMap <String, String>` ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: *How I can store json in this case efficiently without iterating over JSON String.* You can't parse JSON without parsing it.

Comment: *What should be my Hashmap type, definetily not HashMap <String, String> ?* How about `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: What's wrong with a `HashMap<String, Object>`?

Comment: @shmosel: By not iterating, I meant. In 1-liner how can I do like giving jsonString itself as argument. Is there any way to do so ?

I also thought of `HashMap<String, Object>` but not sure, how I can use that to insert key-value pair in 1-liner

Comment: Not if you want to split out the key-value pairs.

Comment: @shmosel and @Henry: Can you please direct me to link or give an example to use `HashMap<String, Object>` ?

Comment: "I meant. In 1-liner": write a method that does it (just 4 or 5 lines anyhow). It can then be called in 1 line.

Comment: Example of what? You don't know how to add an entry to a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` or `Gson` to convert the String into a `Map<String, Object>`.

Here is an example using `Gson`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Map map = gson.fromJson("{\"var\":\"value\"}", Map.class);
    System.out.println("map = " + map);
}
```

You can get an example of the `ObjectMapper` in action over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525152/1490322).

Answer (score 5):

you can try  following code.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> mapdataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    Map<String, Object> MapObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    MapObj.put("windowHandle", "current");
    MapObj.put("id", "{a67fc38c-10e6-4c5e-87dc-dd45134db570}");
    mapdataList.add(MapObj);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject jObject = new JsonObject();
    JsonParser jP = new JsonParser();
    jObject.add("data", jP.parse(gson.toJson(mapdataList)));
    System.out.println(jObject.toString());
```