# Parse JSON as Map of Map for Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json

How to parse JSON like:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "subKey1" : {
      "field1": "value",
      "field2": "value"
    },
    "subKey2": {
      "field1": "value",
      "field2": "value"
    }
  },
  "key2": {
    "subKey1" : {
      "field1": "value",
      "field2": "value"
    },
    "subKey2": {
      "field1": "value",
      "field2": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

to get Object structure like:

```
  // key*       subKey*
Map<String, Map<String, DataType>> map;


public class DataType {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

}
```

If this structure is too complicated, how to parse 
just a map of DataType at least?

Comment: "parsing" json is trivial in python: `d = json.loads(s)`. What you want to know is how to convert a `dict(list(dict())` into a class...

Comment: Your structure is not a map of maps, but rather a map of arrays. To just parse a simple map of Map<String, DataType> follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json

Comment: corrected some mistakes in JSON structure

Comment: nedalekie li4nosti zaminusili

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is quite simple:

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, DataType>>> typeRef = 
        new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, DataType>>>() {};
Map<String, Map<String, DataType>> configMap = jsonMapper.readValue(strJson, typeRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have been dealing with this same issue. I've managed to get it to string then look for the string manually by using...

```
String string1 = "example of response";
string1.contains(response.body().getAsJsonObject().toString());
```

Another alternative would be to use regex (http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) to extract the string you want replacing characters like } and ] with a comma...

Hope this helps in some way. Sorry it's not very convenient