# Split string in java in form of key value pair

Tags: java, split, key-value

I am new in java so this might seem to be a silly question for many of you, but please help me out. I have a string like

```
{"Key1":50.0,"Key2":60.0,"Key3 Roll":80.0}
```

I want to split it in the form of a key-value pair. I want it like String key = key1 and Double value = 50.0 for each iteration.

Comment: Looks like Json. Use some JSON library like Jackson and parse it into a `Map<String,Double>` directly.

Comment: Look at [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json)