# Deserializing a HashMap into a POJO and setting empty fields to null?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, objectmapper

I have a JSON response coming in which I parse as such:

```
        List<LinkedHashMap> jsonResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonResponse, List.class);
```

The JSON response begins with a '{', which is why I have to deserialize it into a List class, and nested in the List are LinkedHashMaps, which I'm not sure if I can directly deserialize into my custom POJO. I'm attempting to convert each HashMap to my custom POJO here:

```
        for (LinkedHashMap res : jsonResponse) {
            ProductsByInstitution resObj = objectMapper.convertValue(res, ProductsByInstitution.class);
        }
```

But, this custom POJO has extra optional fields which may or may not be included in the JSON response. What ends up happening is the Integer / Double fields excluded in the JSON response are automatically set to 0 or 0.0, respectively. I want them to be null.

EDIT:

Still receiving 0's for empty fields.

Code I tried:

```
        TypeReference<List<ProductsByInstitution>> typeRef
                = new TypeReference<List<ProductsByInstitution>>() {};
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        List<ProductsByInstitution> objs = objectMapper.readValue(lambdaResponse, typeRef);
```

The last line is where the error is pointing to.

POJO class:

```
public class ProductsByInstitiution {
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String status;

    private int buy;

    private int offer;

    private int max;

    private int min;

    private double figure;

.... (Getters and setters)
```

So a JSON response might look like this:

```
id: 0
name: "Place"
status: "Good"
buy: 50
min: 20
```

Then when deserialization happens, figure, max, and offer are being set to 0 / 0.0

Comment: Objectmapper uses a linked hashmap when deserializing a List.class. To make it a List of a certain type you need a TypeReference
for an example see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json

but in case of list just use :
TypeReference<List<String>>
(and replace String with the actual type)

Comment: Check updated OP

Comment: Posted POJO code in OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive type `int` or `double` can't represent `null`. Use wrapper class `Integer` or `Double` which can represent null value.

```
public class ProductsByInstitiution {
   private Integer id;
   private Integer max;
   private Double figure;
   ...
}
```